# Using RAG and Vectorsearch to enumerate all entries matching a condition

Tags: langchain, openaiembeddings, mistral-7b, qdrant

I have a Qdrant instance with almost 2000 documents.
Each document describe a Product.

I would like search products with query like: "Enumerate all Products made after year 2021".

But with this type of question I get only one product.

Is RAG the correct way to achieve my intent?

I'm using OpenAI embeddings

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Does your product metadata contain the manufacturing date? That sounds like something that should be solved based on the metadata filters, not the semantic search itself.